# How to get cursor from a row number

Tags: android, sqlite

I use SQLite in android development. When I insert a row using insert, I get the number of the row. However, I want the KEY_ID which is the primary key of the table. I used the function below, but I got:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
    at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong_native(Native Method)
    at android.database.CursorWindow.getInt(CursorWindow.java:434)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:93)
    at winterfarmer.timemama.DataBaseAdapter.insertData(DataBaseAdapter.java:89)
    at winterfarmer.timemama.ManagerActivity.addNewRecord2DB(ManagerActivity.java:106)
    at winterfarmer.timemama.ManagerActivity.addNewRecord(ManagerActivity.java:100)
    at winterfarmer.timemama.ManagerActivity.addNewRecord2DB(ManagerActivity.java:106)
    at winterfarmer.timemama.ManagerActivity.addNewRecord(ManagerActivity.java:100)
    at winterfarmer.timemama.ManagerActivity.setRecordOK(ManagerActivity.java:92)
    at winterfarmer.timemama.ManagerActivity.setRecord(ManagerActivity.java:78)
    at winterfarmer.timemama.ManagerActivity.onActivityResult(ManagerActivity.java:64)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3890)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3511)
```

How can i fix this bug?

```
public int insertData(RecordInfo recordInfo) {
    Log.d(TAG, "insertData");

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

    initialValues.put(KEY_HOUR, recordInfo.hour);
    initialValues.put(KEY_MINUTE, recordInfo.minute);
    initialValues.put(KEY_REPEAT, recordInfo.repeat);

    long rowId = db.insert(DB_ALARM_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    assert rowId >= 0 : "insertData failed";
    Log.d(TAG, "insertData, rowId = " + rowId);
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT last_insert_rowid() from "
            + DB_ALARM_TABLE, null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    int colId = cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID);
    Log.d(TAG, "insertData, colId = " + colId);
    assert colId >= 0 : "insertData failed";
    return cur.getInt(colId);
}
```

Comment: Please upload your full stack trace.

Comment: And which one is line 89 of your adapter please?

Comment: For future reference, please don't post stack traces or code as comments, they aren't readable. Edit the question instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Cursor doc:

> public abstract int getColumnIndex (String columnName)
>
> Since: API Level 1 
>   Returns the zero-based index for the given column 
>   name, or -1 if the column doesn't exist. If you expect the column to exist 
>   use getColumnIndexOrThrow(String) instead, which will make the error more clear

So that would explain the problem better.

Anyway, back to your **actual problem**:

The problem is that `KEY_ID` is not a result column of your select query (the result will not be named `KEY_ID`, even though the value originally comes from the `KEY_ID` column). It will have only one column result, so it doesn't make sense to ask for the column index. `colId` will be 0. You can directly do:

```
Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT last_insert_rowid() from "
        + DB_ALARM_TABLE, null);
cur.moveToFirst();
return cur.getInt(0);
```

Comment: private static final String DB_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + DB_ALARM_TABLE
   + " (" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
   + KEY_HOUR + " INT NOT NULL , " + KEY_MINUTE + " INT NOT NULL , "
   + KEY_REPEAT + " INT NOT NULL " + " )";

Comment: Sorry, my first answer was not correct, as you can see I edited it to explain your real problem

Comment: Thank you- reminded me to include the row_id as a column output, and thus included in the recordset results!

Answer (score 0):

```
int colId = cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID);
```

I recommend changing this to

```
int colId = cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ID);
```

If that column doesn't exist, which seems the probable cause (as Guillaume pointed out), you'll get a much more informative exception and it's simpler than having to check for a `-1` return value.

Comment: @CodeBoy: No that's not your problem, see my answer - your problem is that you're not selecting KEY_ID in your query, you're selecting last_insert_rowid()